# Any way to import all cases from one FogBugz account to another (both hosted)

Tags: fogbugz-on-demand

Question says it all.  I have two accounts on two separate hosted fogbugz-on-demand.  One holds all the cases that needs to be moved to the other.  I have admin access on both.  Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took contacting fogbugz directly to accomplish this.  Since I am using the free hosted option for both accounts there is a $100 one time charge.